# Drawing a circular segment in 3D-Space

Tags: vector, 3d, geometry

I am trying to draw a circular segment (cs) in 3D. The given data is the start & end point of the cs and the origin.

My idea was to first transform the circle onto the unit circle (ignoring the Z coord) and calculating the angle of the start & end.I could now generate a list of points with the loop below that contains the data of a circle segment on a virtual plane in 3D-Space. The last step was to rotate the points around the point between start & end.

The problem is that my loop returns a circle segment with plausible coord and radius but it cuts the line at the start & the end.

My code:

```
Visual3D lines;
Vector3D start = new Vector3D(2, 2, 0); //2, 2, 0
Vector3D end = new Vector3D(4, 4, 2); //4, 4, 2
Vector3D up = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);
Vector3D middle = pkm.ToVector3D(); //pkm.ToVector3D()
double r = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(start.X - middle.X, 2) + Math.Pow(start.Y - middle.Y, 2) + Math.Pow(start.Z - middle.Z, 2)); //Implement Check mechanism for possible points
List<Point3D> points = new List<Point3D>();

//calc
Vector3D idealStart = start - middle; 
Vector3D idealEnd = end - middle;
idealStart.Z = 0;
idealEnd.Z = 0;
idealStart.Normalize();
idealEnd.Normalize();

double delta = Math.Acos((Vector3D.DotProduct(up, idealStart)) / (up.Length * idealStart.Length));
double phi = Math.Acos((Vector3D.DotProduct(up, idealEnd)) / (up.Length * idealEnd.Length));

for (double i = phi; i <= delta; i += 0.01)
{
    points.Add(new Point3D(Math.Sin(i) * r + middle.X, Math.Cos(i) * r + middle.Y, middle.Z));
}



Vector3D half = (end - start) / 2;
middle = middle - start - half; //switch start with end
middle.Normalize();

lines = meschi.GetLinie(points, 2, Colors.Wheat); //Transforms the type of data
lines = meschi.ModelDrehenUmPunkt(lines, ((end + start) / 2).ToPoint3D(), middle, -Vector3D.AngleBetween(end - start, start)); // Final Rotation
```

Example of my result:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xktbicrgtichsm1/circle_segment.JPG

Has anyone a clue why the code doesn't draw the full circle segment?

Thanks in advance!